# How to add a chart in iReport Designer 4.1.2 to my designer view?

Tags: ireport

**Problem**

I have created a blank report (mychart.jrxml).I cannot figure out how to add a chart to my blank report in the designer view.

**What I have tried**

I went into the samples folder under the iReport folder of the installation and opened up one of the samples that has a chart. In that example (charts.jrxml) the chart definition is expanded in the **Summary** section on the left tree navigation bar.

So I go to my blank (mychart.jrxml) file and try to right click "Summary" to see if I can add any type of component but I cannot.

**UPDATE**

I have noticed that in the main navigation bar the the **Palette** menu item under tools is empty.

Does anybody know how? Do I have to get the pay edition to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Comment: I have just found the answer:

Click on **Window->Palette** This will open up a Palette Widnow on the right. Still the palette shows empty under tools though. A little confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official answer: Click on **Window->Palette** This will open up a Palette Widnow on the right